Core Data Unit Testing with Swift Testing - keep getting "attempt to insert nil"
I use Swift Testing to unit test my Core Data interactions. To not "spoil" my SQL database, I use an in-memory database instead. This is how I implemented my persistentContainer variable, passing an environment variable to set the storeType to NSInMemoryStoreType when unit testing:
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
    description.type = storeType
    
    // Pass the data model filename to the container’s initializer.
    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: CoreDataStack.dataStoreName)
    if storeType == NSInMemoryStoreType {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
    }
    
    
            fatalError("Failed to load persistent stores: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()

My problem: I keep getting this error in totally different tests. I simply cannot reproduce when it happens. I happens during saving, deleting, etc. Or not at all.
Thread 2: "-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil"

I searched for solutions and tried a couple of things, but don't really know where to go first to find the issue. Is it maybe because Swift Testing executes the tests in different threads, all accessing the same database?
The latest stack trace is:
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804b70ec __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018008ede8 objc_exception_throw + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018053d62c -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018054627c -[__NSCFSet addObject:].cold.2 + 0
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001805324dc -[__NSCFSet removeObject:] + 0
    5   CoreData                            0x0000000186d1d664 -[NSManagedObjectContext _processPendingDeletions:withInsertions:withUpdates:withNewlyForgottenList:withRemovedChangedObjects:] + 388
    6   CoreData                            0x0000000186d0bc28 -[NSManagedObjectContext _processRecentChanges:] + 1900
    7   CoreData                            0x0000000186d20e0c _performRunLoopAction + 376
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018041a2ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180414cac __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 528
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018041511c __CFRunLoopRun + 896
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180414960 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 536
    12  XCTestCore                          0x000000010450a920 +[XCTWaiter _synchronouslyWaitForTimeInterval:] + 112
    13  XCTestCore                          0x000000010450b058 -[XCTWaiter _performWait:manager:completionHandler:] + 912
    14  XCTestCore                          0x0000000104509004 -[XCTWaiter _waitForExpectations:timeout:enforceOrder:synchronously:completionHandler:] + 520
    15  XCTestCore                          0x0000000104508dac -[XCTWaiter waitForExpectations:timeout:enforceOrder:] + 108
    16  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d9898 __XCTAsyncEnumerateWithWaiter_block_invoke + 276
    17  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d99fc __XCTAsyncEnumerate_block_invoke.98 + 52
    18  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d999c __XCTAsyncEnumerateWithWaiter_block_invoke_2 + 44
    19  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d874c __72-[XCTExecutionWorker enqueueTestIdentifiersToRun:testIdentifiersToSkip:]_block_invoke_3 + 124
    20  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044e55a8 -[XCTTestRunSession executeTestsWithIdentifiers:skippingTestsWithIdentifiers:completion:] + 280
    21  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d8690 __72-[XCTExecutionWorker enqueueTestIdentifiersToRun:testIdentifiersToSkip:]_block_invoke_2 + 120
    22  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d9864 __XCTAsyncEnumerateWithWaiter_block_invoke + 224
    23  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d99fc __XCTAsyncEnumerate_block_invoke.98 + 52
    24  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d8510 XCTAsyncEnumerateWithWaiter + 500
    25  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d82d0 __72-[XCTExecutionWorker enqueueTestIdentifiersToRun:testIdentifiersToSkip:]_block_invoke + 108
    26  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d87c4 -[XCTExecutionWorker runWithError:] + 76
    27  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d6808 __25-[XCTestDriver _runTests]_block_invoke.200 + 52
    28  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044ea5f8 -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForTestBundle:inBlock:] + 180
    29  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d61f4 -[XCTestDriver _runTests] + 1088
    30  XCTestCore                          0x00000001044d7f90 _XCTestMain + 116
    31  libXCTestBundleInject.dylib         0x0000000102c5b168 __RunTests_block_invoke_2 + 0
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803e3d88 __CFMachPortPerform + 172
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018041ba6c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018041b034 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 496
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180415628 __CFRunLoopRun + 2188
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180414960 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 536
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000190183b10 GSEventRunModal + 160
    38  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185aa2b40 -[UIApplication _run] + 796
    39  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185aa6d38 UIApplicationMain + 124
    40  EasyFPU.debug.dylib                 0x000000010390da14 __debug_main_executable_dylib_entry_point + 64
    41  dyld                                0x0000000102d79410 start_sim + 20
    42  ???                                 0x0000000102efa274 0x0 + 4344226420
)

Any hint is appreciated.

Maybe the stacktrace when it crash might help, as seeing where the issue is.

Try using a test plan or running the test repeatedly to find where the test is guaranteed to fail (maybe not on the first run)
Or turn off parallel running test and try run your tests if its not failure, this mean that one of your object is not thread safe
